# SQL Server .nodes() XML parent nodes by name

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

```
    declare @xmlsample xml =
'<root>
    <solution>
        <solutionnumber>1</solutionnumber>
            <productgroup>
                <productcategory>
                    <price>100</price>
                    <title>Some product</title>
                    <tax>1</tax>
                </productcategory>
            </productgroup>
            <productcategory2>
                    <price>200</price>
                    <title>Some other product</title>
                    <tax>2</tax>
            </productcategory2>
    </solution>
    <solution>
        <solutionnumber>2</solutionnumber>
            <productcategory2>
                    <price>200</price>
                    <title>Some other product</title>
                    <tax>2</tax>
            </productcategory2>
    </solution>
</root>'

SELECT 
    --T.C.value('(./ancestor::ns1:solutionNumber)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS solutionnumber ?? no clue
    T.C.value('(price)[1]', 'numeric(18,2)') AS price
    ,T.C.value('(title)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS title
    ,T.C.value('(tax)[1]', 'numeric(18,2)') AS tax
FROM @xmlsample.nodes('//node()[title]') AS T(C)
```

A representation of the XML I am attempting to shred in SQL Server 2008 r2. I find the "title" node and grab the values I need that are in the product category. Now I would like to get the "solution number" however this could be one or more parent nodes above the product as there are certain product "groups."

How would I go about check the parent nodes by name ("solutionnumber") until I find it? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Incorrect terminology on my part. Still looking for "solutionnumber", however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I was going about this backwards. Multiple cross applies will do the job. Thanks to some assistance on another forum.

```
SELECT 
    --T.C.value('(./ancestor::ns1:solutionNumber)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS solutionnumber ?? no clue
    m.c.value('(solutionnumber)[1]', 'int') as solutionnumber
    ,T.C.value('(price)[1]', 'numeric(18,2)') AS price
    ,T.C.value('(title)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS title
    ,T.C.value('(tax)[1]', 'numeric(18,2)') AS tax
FROM  @xmlsample.nodes ('//solution') as m (c)
cross apply m.c.nodes ('.//node()[title]') as t(C)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct way to my knowledge. However, you can use COALESCE to search your way up:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(T.C.value('../solutionnumber[1]', 'INT'),
             T.C.value('../../solutionnumber[1]', 'INT'),
             T.C.value('../../../solutionnumber[1]', 'INT')) solutionnumber,
    T.C.value('(price)[1]', 'numeric(18,2)') AS price,
    T.C.value('(title)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS title,
    T.C.value('(tax)[1]', 'numeric(18,2)') AS tax
  FROM
    @xmlsample.nodes('//node()[title]') AS T ( C )
```

Note that `<solutionnumber`> is really a sibling of one of the ancestors and not an ancestor itself.

This solution requires you to know the maximum depth ahead of time.

---

You can also use this solution, if you rather go forward than backwards:

```
SELECT solutionNodes.solutionNode.value('solutionnumber[1]','INT') AS solutionnumber,
    T.C.value('(price)[1]', 'numeric(18,2)') AS price,
    T.C.value('(title)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS title,
    T.C.value('(tax)[1]', 'numeric(18,2)') AS tax
FROM @xmlsample.nodes('//solution') AS solutionNodes (solutionNode)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT solutionNodes.solutionNode.query('.')) solutions(solutionXML)
CROSS APPLY solutions.solutionXML.nodes('//node()[title]') T ( C )
```

It uses the fact that the `<solutionnumber`> tag is a direct child of a `<solution`> tag. First all `<solution`> tags are found. Than all its title descendants are found with a cross apply. Because you cannot use the nodes function on a node there is the calculation of "query('.')" in between.

Other than above solution, this one can handle any distance between the `<solution`> tag abd the `<title`> tag.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support going backwards to the ancestor, so here's a roundabout way of `caching` the pointer to an ancestor while descending into the XML.

```
declare @xmlsample xml =
'<root>
    <solution>
        <solutionnumber>1</solutionnumber>
            <productgroup>
                <productcategory>
                    <price>100</price>
                    <title>Some product</title>
                    <tax>1</tax>
                </productcategory>
            </productgroup>
            <productcategory2>
                    <price>200</price>
                    <title>Some other product</title>
                    <tax>2</tax>
            </productcategory2>
    </solution>
    <solution>
        <solutionnumber>2</solutionnumber>
            <productcategory2>
                    <price>200</price>
                    <title>Some other product</title>
                    <tax>2</tax>
            </productcategory2>
    </solution>
</root>';

WITH Xml_CTE AS
(
     SELECT node.query('*') AS children,
            node.value('fn:local-name(.)','varchar(100)') localName,
            node.exist('title') IsTitleParent,
            CAST(null as xml) as solution
       FROM @xmlsample.nodes('/*') AS root(node)
  UNION ALL
     SELECT node.query('*') AS children,
            node.value('fn:local-name(.)','varchar(100)') localName,
            node.exist('title') IsTitleParent,
            CASE WHEN node.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') = 'solution'
                 THEN node.query('.')
                 ELSE solution END
       FROM Xml_CTE x
CROSS APPLY x.children.nodes('*') AS child(node)
)
SELECT solution.value('(solution/solutionnumber/text())[1]', 'int') solutionNumber
      ,children.value('(price)[1]', 'numeric(18,2)') price
      ,children.value('(title)[1]', 'varchar(50)') title
      ,children.value('(tax)[1]', 'numeric(18,2)') tax
  FROM Xml_CTE
 WHERE IsTitleParent = 1 -- matches .nodes('//node()[title]')
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work perfectly...

```
Declare @SomeXML XML
SET @SomeXML = '<SomeValue>GGGG</SomeValue><SomeValue>MMMM</SomeValue><SomeValue>AAA</SomeValue>'

select ROW_NUMBER() over ( order by b), b.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
from @SomeXML.nodes('(/SomeValue)') AS a(b)
```